# how to create and set link in top navigation in mediawiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

everyone I'm newby to this mediawiki platform and I'm stuck at this situation , my problem is that I am unable to the desired page by clicking the link ,

Any relevant help would be more than welcome , 
Thanks
Priya Patel

i wants to navigate on my createprofessionalprofile link in the screenshot.

Comment: post any code snippet related to your problem

Comment: Please try to describe your problem in more detail. What exactly do you want to achieve, what have you tried, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Create Professional Profile' : `array('Create Professional Profile')`, this is add into `mediawiki/language/message.en`